# Is the SVG def element editable

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got an svg with a defs element, like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 250 330" onclick="tweenGloss()">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="174.62" y1="-20.2" x2="75.38" y2="350.2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#d4af37"/>
      <stop offset="0.14" stop-color="#fefdfb"/>
      <stop offset="0.27" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
      <stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#816e26"/>
      <stop offset="0.59" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
      <stop offset="0.82" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
      <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#fff"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <title>StickerBorder</title>
  <rect x="5" y="292.04" width="240" height="30.58" style="fill: #aa4c4e;stroke: #4f2426;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 4px"/>
  <polygon points="6.71 4 6.71 53.09 47.54 53.09 68.22 32.41 245 32.41 246.28 4 6.71 4" style="fill: #2680b8"/>
  <polyline points="5 54.09 47.06 54.09 67.51 33.41 242.31 33.41" style="fill: none;stroke: #184c66;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 4px"/>
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="240" height="320" style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 10px;stroke: url(#grad)"/>
  <circle cx="196.64" cy="292.04" r="21.94" style="fill: #fff;stroke: #4f2426;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 4px"/>
  <text transform="translate(188.7 304.34)" style="font-size: 28.58350944519043px;fill: #1d1d1b;font-family: KG Second Chances Sketch">7</text>
</svg>
```

I'm appending a couple of children to this via javascript like so :

```
<lineargradient id="glossgrad" x1="22.3" y1="342.88" x2="227.7" y2="-12.88" gradientunits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.2" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
</lineargradient>

<rect x="5" y="5" width="240" height="320" style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 10px;stroke: url(#glossgrad)"></rect>
```

So the `lineargradient` "glossgrad" is being added to the `defs` element and the `rect` is being added to the `svg` element. My problem is, the new appended `rect` doesn't appear at all. However if I change the url of the `rect` to the original `lineargradient` url it appears.

So my question is, does the 'defs' element not get updated once it has had it's initial load? Is it sort of cached or something?

Comment: We need to see the code you've written to add elements. It's likely you've added them in the wrong namespace.

Comment: Also SVG is case sensitive so lineargradient is incorrect.

Comment: hint: get rid of xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" and see if it works (Robert's 1st comment above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you append the new linear gradient definitions and rect element. But to answer your question, there are no issues in dynamically appending new elements to svg defs and using them.

Here is a working example:

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

createGradient(svg,'glossgrad',[
  {offset:'5%', 'stop-color':'#f60'},
  {offset:'95%','stop-color':'#ff6'}
]);

var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
    rect.setAttribute('x',60);
    rect.setAttribute('y',80);
    rect.setAttribute('width',50);
    rect.setAttribute('height',50);
    rect.setAttribute('fill','url(#glossgrad)');
    svg.appendChild(rect);

function createGradient(svg,id,stops){
 
  var grad  = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'linearGradient');
  grad.setAttribute('id',id);
  for (var i=0;i<stops.length;i++){
    var attrs = stops[i];
    var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'stop');
    for (var attr in attrs){
      if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)) stop.setAttribute(attr,attrs[attr]);
    }
    grad.appendChild(stop);
  }

  var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') ||
      svg.insertBefore( document.createElementNS(svgNS,'defs'), svg.firstChild);
  return defs.appendChild(grad);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 250 330" onclick="tweenGloss()">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="174.62" y1="-20.2" x2="75.38" y2="350.2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#d4af37"/>
      <stop offset="0.14" stop-color="#fefdfb"/>
      <stop offset="0.27" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
      <stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#816e26"/>
      <stop offset="0.59" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
      <stop offset="0.82" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
      <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#fff"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d6b23f"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <title>StickerBorder</title>
  <rect x="5" y="292.04" width="240" height="30.58" style="fill: #aa4c4e;stroke: #4f2426;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 4px"/>
  <polygon points="6.71 4 6.71 53.09 47.54 53.09 68.22 32.41 245 32.41 246.28 4 6.71 4" style="fill: #2680b8"/>
  <polyline points="5 54.09 47.06 54.09 67.51 33.41 242.31 33.41" style="fill: none;stroke: #184c66;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 4px"/>
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="240" height="320" style="fill: none;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 10px;stroke: url(#grad)"/>
  <circle cx="196.64" cy="292.04" r="21.94" style="fill: #fff;stroke: #4f2426;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 4px"/>
  <text transform="translate(188.7 304.34)" style="font-size: 28.58350944519043px;fill: #1d1d1b;font-family: KG Second Chances Sketch">7</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: As also pointed out by @RobertLongson, the namespaces were the issue, the code I had was pretty similar to this except I was using just `document.createElement`. Switching those to `document.createElementNS` and using the svg namespaceURI sorted it.

Comment: Another possible issue with my code is that I was using `cloneNode` for the rectangle creation, changing that to a `createElementNS` seemed to also be necessary